# function gives error on linux server

Tags: php, windows, linux

I'm using a function i found on php.net(i think) to sort an array based on a value

```
usort($comments, function ($a, $b) { return $b["date"] - $a["date"]; });
```

It's supposed to put newer dates first.Works just fine on windows localhost, gives error on linux server.Why ? Could anyone give me a replacement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using a PHP version < 5.3 on your Linux. Anonymous functions are only available on the latest PHP versions.

```
function mySort($a, $b) { return $b["date"] - $a["date"]; }

usort($comments, 'mySort');
```

Comment: Thats true. i want aware. my server is running on php 5.2 Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Probably because your server does not run PHP 5.3 and [lambda functions](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/17/on-php-5-3-lambda-functions-and-closures) are only available since then. What error do you get?

In general, the code looks correct. A working version for PHP < 5.3 would be:

```
function custom_sort($a, $b) {
    return $b["date"] - $a["date"];
}

usort($comments, "custom_sort");
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess: You Windows server is running PHP 5.3. Your Linux server is running an older version. Support for anonymous functions was added in PHP 5.3.